# Are any two distinct p-Sylow subgroups normal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This is very clear that if we have unique $p$-Sylow subgroup in a group G then it is normal in G by using second Sylow theorem, as single $p$-Sylow subgroup in a group is self conjugate to itself....
Now my ques is that suppose we have two distinct $p$-Sylow subgroups then why can we not use Sylow 2nd theorem here....why can't we use self conjugacy here???

Comment: Any two $p$-Sylow groups are conjugate.  See, e.g., [this](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/group/sylow.html)

Comment: In you statement, do you mean *exactly* two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups, or just an arbitrary pair?

Comment: Just an arbitrary pair

Comment: OK, then I concur with the answer of @freakish and +1 you both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second Sylow theorem implies that every two Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugates. So if there are two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups then obviously none of them is normal, since normal subgroups don't have proper conjugates.

In other words: a Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal if and only if it is a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup.